# "Faking" small caps for a font installed from .ttf files

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Say I have installed a font using something like `otfinst.py` or similar. And say this font doesn't have a small caps version. Is there an easy way to fake small caps in pdflatex? At the moment, text that is supposed to be `sc` just shows up as regular text...

For a one off, I can fake small caps like this (requires `graphicx`):

```
F\scalebox{0.7}{\MakeUppercase{ake small caps}}
```

And I guess what I'd like is a macro that does that. That is, it `scalebox`es and then `MakeUppercase`s all of the lower case letters in its argument. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would produce Postscript Type1 font(s) with e.g. Fontforge and then follow the instructions of 'Tutorial 1 The Basics' of [fontinstallationguide.pdf](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/fontinstallationguide.html). It does include virtual fonts for faked small caps by default, as well as for slanted cuts.
There are scripts like [installfont](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/installfont.html) that does all the work. You just need the command line options and wait for a minute or two.

Comment: This is obviously the best solution (apart from perhaps emailing the creator of the font and requesting a small caps version), but given the hassle I've been through to install the normal version of the font, I don't want to play around with the fonts in this way...

Comment: It's not so much hassle as it looks. It's a step by step recipe. In the end it simply works with '\textsc' and '\scshape' and you don't need any extra macro. Maybe about 30 mins if you do it your first time.